# count number of rows within 10 minutes of each other in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have a table of transaction with their date-time. I'd like to count number of clusters of visits within 10 minutes of each other.

```
input=
ID  visitTime
1   11/10/2017 15:01
1   11/10/2017 15:02
1   11/10/2017 15:19
1   11/10/2017 15:21
1   11/10/2017 15:25
1   11/11/2017 15:32
1   11/11/2017 15:39
1   11/11/2017 15:41
```

Here, there is a cluster starting on `11/10/2017 15:01` with 2 adjacent visits, one on `11/10/2017 15:19` with 3 visits (2 clusters on the date of `11/10/2017`). There is another cluster on `11/11/2017 15:32` with 3 calls. Giving the table below.

```
output =
ID    Date    Cluster_count    Clusters_with_3ormore_visits
1     11/10/2017    2          1
1     11/11/2017    1          1
```

What I did:

```
input %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(visitTime) %>%
mutate(nextvisit = lead(visitTime),
     gapTime = as.numeric(interval(visitTime,nextvisit), 'minutes'),
     repeated = ifelse(gapTime<= 10,1,0))
```

This can show the start and end of a sequence of visits, but doesn't give me a key to separate them and group them by.

Appreciate any hints/ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `cumsum` typically solves these issues when you have a column that says if a specific data point is in a different group than the previous one.

I made a few small changes, namely used `lastvisit` instead of `nextvisit` and `difftime` instead of `interval` (not sure where that function comes from).

```
input %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(visitTime) %>%
    mutate(lastvisit = lag(visitTime),
           gapTime = as.numeric(difftime(visitTime, lastvisit, 'minutes')),
           sameCluster = is.na(gapTime) | gapTime > 10,
           cluster = cumsum(sameCluster))
```

(`is.na(gapTime)` only handles first row, for which `gapTime` isn't defined.)

Comment: You are right that `cumsum` is the answer! But the change from `nextvisit` to `lastvisit` messes up the result. I replaced my `repeated` col with your Boolean `sameCluster` one and added the cumsum and it numbers the clusters correctly. If you don't mind, please make those updates so I can mark it solved. Also interval is from `lubridate` package :)

Comment: I would change that, just in my case, if I only add `sameCluster` and `cumsum`, I get different cluster numbers. Did you also change anything else? I believe that comparing it with previous `visitTime` makes it easier to understand.

Comment: this is what I ran: `input %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(visitTime) %>%
mutate(nextvisit = lead(visitTime),
     gapTime = as.numeric(interval(visitTime,nextvisit), 'minutes'),
     sameCluster = is.na(gapTime) | gapTime > 10,
         cluster = cumsum(sameCluster))` which works correctly. I couldn't figure out why we get different results... But I'm going to accept your answer. thanks again.